# Character extraction from image of combed field

Tags: python, image, opencv, character, extract

I am currently working on handwritten character recognition from a form iamge. Everything works pretty well so far, but I was hoping I could get some insight on extracting character from an image of a boxed or a "combed" field

For example, after a specific field has been cropped and binazarized (with otu's method), I'm left with something like this:

[Binary Field Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwSkH.png)

For character recogntion, I have a trained CNN model using the emnist dataset. In order to predict the characters, I have to extract the characters one by one. What would be the best way to extract the characters from the boxes?

Currently, I am using a pretty trivial method of just find groupings of non-white lines of horizontal and vertical pixels that take up a certain number of pixels in relation to the image width and height. For example, I would find horizontal lines that consists of at least 90% non-white pixels and group the ones that have concurrent y coordinates to form a rectangle object which would be the horizontal lines found on the image (which should constist of two lines/rectangles, for top and bottom). For vertical lines I do a similar thing except I would end up with {2 * charLength} lines. I use these values to crop out each character. However, it is not perfect.

Here are some issues with this:

- Field is not always perfectly straight (rotation is slightly off). I am already applying SURF and homography to the original image, which does a very good job but it is not perfect.
- If a user writes a "1" that takes up the entire height of the box, it will most likely falsly indicate that as a vertical line of the box.
- The coordinates don't always match up with the original image and the input image. Therefore, part of the field will be cropped out sometimes. To fix this, I am currently extracting a surrounding part of the field  (as seen in the image) but this can also cause problems because the form can have other vertical and horizontal lines very close to some fields. This will cause my current trivial method to not work properly.

Is there a better way to do this? One thing is that I have to keep performance in mind. I was thinking of doing SURF matching again for just the field image, but doing it for the entire form page takes very long, so I am not sure if I want to do it again for each field that I am reading.

I was hoping someone would have suggestions. I am using OpenCV for image processing, but solution in words is fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late response, but I ended up using the contour feature that OpenCV had to extract the character portion.

When OpenCV finds the contours of the images, it sets up a hierarchy system of contours. The first level ended up being the very outer box so I was able to just grab the contours of the next level to extract the characters.

It didn't work 100% in the beginning, but after some additional image processing I was able to extract the characters properly for at least 99% of cases.